# Enum. Can't find what's wrong

Tags: c, enums, switch-statement

In a header file:

```
  typedef struct apartment_t* Apartment;
  typedef enum { EMPTY, WALL } SquareType;

struct apartment_t {
    SquareType** squares;
    int width;
    int length;
    int price;
};
```

in the source file:

```
int apartmentTotalArea(Apartment apartment) {

    int countEmpty = 0;

    for (int i=0;i<apartment->length;i++)
        for (int j=0;j<apartment->width;j++) {
            SquareType Square = apartment->squares[i][j];
            switch(Square) {
                case Square.EMPTY: // Bad
                    countEmpty++;
                    break;

                case Square.WALL: // Bad
                    break;
            }
        }
```

This function counts the empty spots in a given 2d array. I'm facing a problem in the switch, it'll mark both cases as bad statements. What's wrong with my code? Thank you.

Comment: `Type **` is not a 2D array and it cannot represent one! It is a pointer to pointer to `Type`. And provide a [mcve].

Comment: Where did you get `IsEmpty.` from?

Comment: @immibis That was supposed to be Square. My bad!

Comment: @Olaf Are you saying it is not possible for an array of arrays to represent a 2D array? Because that's rubbish.

Comment: How are you initializing squares?

Comment: @immibis: Where did I say that?? Where is an array of arrays in the question? `Type **` is a pointer to pointer. It can represent an array of **pointers** to `Type` at best, but not an "array of array" which very well is a 2D array. Please read the question and my comment correctly. If that still not helps, assume `int **p;` `*p` is a pointer. While for the correct pointer to a 2D array, it was `int (*p)[COLS];` where `*p` has type `int [COLS]`. Try this with a compliant compiler and warnings enabled.

Comment: `case Square.EMPTY:` -> `case EMPTY:`.

Comment: @RSahu Worked :) Appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as `Square.EMPTY` or `Square.WALL` in your code. Use:

```
switch(Square) {
    case EMPTY:  // Juse EMPTY, not Square.EMPTY
        countEmpty++;
        break;

    case WALL:
        break;
}
```